# Using WSL Windows 10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd

Installed Ubuntu distribution under Windows 10.

> ```
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
> Release: 20.04
> Codename: focal
> ```

When running `sudo systemctl status` command or `sudo systemctl start kafka` in Linux environment I get this message:

> ```
> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
> Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
> ```

How to decide? How to start Unit processes?

Comment: What did you find when searching for the last error on the web? Any helpful links? Please, pretty please, show a little bit of your research before posting a question.

Comment: I have find this, but can not get how to apply it: https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie

Comment: Ok, but you didn't find this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52197246/1256347 Please Megan, edit your question and include what you want to do (start kafka on wsl I assume), what version wsl you have, what you've searched for, what you found and why what you've found did not work (error, unclear instructions, etc...)